# Custom SOAP Faults in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

Please let me know how to throw custom SOAP faults from service activators in spring integration. If I have a service activator for errorChannel, what should be the return value from the handling method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring Integration WS module is fully based on the Spring WS project. The best way to address your requirements is to follow with standard approach from there: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/html/server.html#server-endpoint-exception-resolver.

I'd follow with something like @SoapFault on some business Exception and won't worry about error-channel at all!

Comment: Hi, I got your point. But will I be able to customize the faultStringOrReason on the fly. For example Below is my soap fault class @SoapFault(faultCode = FaultCode.CUSTOM, customFaultCode="{namespace}Server Error", faultStringOrReason="Error encountered when processing request message.")
public class SystemFault extends BusinessException{ }. What I am looking forward is a) if new SystemFault() is thrown, then the faultstring should be "Error encountered when processing request message." . If I throw new SystemFault("custom message"), faultstring should be "custom message"

Comment: Well, for that purpose I guess you should implement your own `AbstractSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver` and decide what to place into the `SoapFaultDefinitionEditor` on your own. See `SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver` for details.

Comment: Hi Artem.. Got it working. One more question. In case of custom fault code, is there any way not to specify the namespace ? if I specify the namespace, the fault code is coming as ,<faultcode xmlns:----- >custom fault code<.faultcode>. But how should i prevent xmlns to get printed along with fault code?

Comment: That should not be a problem. The correct XML processor can live with that. Not sure how that `xmlns` appears, because it is a part of the top-level `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`. From other side it is a separate question. Sorry, I don't have an immediate answer for the problem. Seems for me that worked well for me when I got deal with SOAP...

Comment: Hi Artem. Thanks for your comment. Moved the same to a different question.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694048/custom-soap-faults-in-spring-integration-fault-code-namespace