# Custom SOAP Faults in spring integration Fault code namespace

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-ws

I am trying to implement custom soap faults like below:

```
@SoapFault(faultCode = FaultCode.CUSTOM, customFaultCode="{namespace}Server Error", faultStringOrReason="Error encountered when processing request message.") 
public class SystemFault extends BusinessException{ }.
```

The soap fault thrown is of the below format:

```
<.SOAP-ENV:Fault>
     <.faultcode xmlns:ns0="namespace">ns0:star:Server Error<./faultcode>
     <.faultstring xml:lang="en">Error Encountered when processing the request.<./faultstring>
 <./SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

As you can see, fault code tag is appearing with a namespace declaration. Please let me know if there is anyway to avoid that. The format of soap fault client is expecting is:

```
<.soapenv:Fault xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5">
     <.faultcode>star:Custom Fault Code<./faultcode>
     <.faultstring>Custom Fault message<./faultstring>
<./soapenv:Fault>
```

I Checked `AbstractSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver.resolveExceptionInternal()` method and it is expecting `QName` instance for fault code and not a string. Please let me know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you almost there with your `customFaultCode` syntax!

Let's revise that JavaDoc one more time:

```
/**
 * The custom fault code, to be used if {@link #faultCode()} is set to {@link FaultCode#CUSTOM}.
 *
 * <p>The format used is that of {@link QName#toString()}, i.e. "{" + Namespace URI + "}" + local part, where the
 * namespace is optional.
 *
 * <p>Note that custom Fault Codes are only supported on SOAP 1.1.
 */
String customFaultCode() default "";
```

So, I've just decided to see what is that `{@link QName#toString()}`:

```
public String toString() {
    if (namespaceURI.equals(XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI)) {
        return localPart;
    } else {
        return "{" + namespaceURI + "}" + localPart;
    }
}
```

Where that `XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI` is like:

```
public static final String NULL_NS_URI = "";
```

From here it looks like it would be enough for you to declare that like plain string:

```
customFaultCode="Server Error"
```

Although if you want to move the `xmlns` declaration to the top-level you should consider to use more low-level API in your custom `AbstractSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver` extension:

```
((SoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse()).getEnvelope().addNamespaceDeclaration("star", "http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5");
```

And right, use your `customFaultCode` with raw prefix:

```
customFaultCode="star:Server Error"
```

Comment: Hi Artem, Thanks for the detailed mail. I found an issue with this. There is a method call from AbstractSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver.getFaultDefinition() like below fault = soap11Body.addFault(definition.getFaultCode(), faultStringOrReason, definition.getLocale()); So in SaajSoap11Body, there is an Assert statement Assert.hasLength(faultCode.getNamespaceURI(), "faultCode's namespaceUri cannot be empty");. This is causing issue.

Comment: Well, if you are able to declare your `xmlns` on the root `<Fault>` element, you still can declare it like before with the `{namespace}` instance. According the `FaultImpl` it should `ensureNamespaceIsDeclared()`, meaning reusing and existing `xmlns`.

Comment: I am able to bring the namespace declaration to <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5"> by overriding the method resolveExceptionInternal. But I am not able to bring the namespace declaration to <fault> tag

Comment: Well, I'd follow with the `AxiomSoap11Body.addFault()` source code. And yes, would change the `messageFactory` to Axiom.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an old post but just wanna try to help out. I think you should not worry about fault code and faultdescription. There is actually a third field in the soapFault element whitch is named detail. This element has two subelements named code and description. Use this to carry the fault information.

Check this post: http://memorynotfound.com/spring-ws-add-detail-soapfault-exception-handling/

Hope this can help.
Thanks

Comment: Please write relevant sections of the answer here as links might change over time.